# flat rate Quote for indy video game

Tags: quote, video, video-games, sound-design

Hi everyone,

I have to give a quote of a flat rate for a small Independent Video game. I am primarily a musical composer, but going to be doing some basic sound design on this one. I need a flat rate quote that will be reasonable for a small video game start up and still reasonable for my time. There will be a small musical element as well, but I will ask for your input on the sound design side of things. I will put a list of sounds below, please let me know what you think. I was thinking a couple of grand, but really value any input from you all.. thanks a lot for your time..

   Debris falling

   Two materials hitting each other (around 10 – 20 sounds, generic, can be used for different objects of same material, e.g. wood on metal)

   Glass breaking

   Opening doors

   Slamming doors

   Door knob turning

   Windows opening

   Running water (tap)

   Fire crackling

   Fire extinguisher spray (starting the spray, full/strong spray loop, running out spray, stop spray without running out)

   Break and pulling out fire extinguisher pin

   Footsteps

   Crawling

   Crouching

   Breathing (normal, medium, heavy)

   Coughing (light, medium, heavy)

   Hurt/Gasp (for when the character gets too close to the fire)

   Hurt/Yell/Grunt (for when the character is touching the fire)

   Climbing down rope ladder

   Rope ladder unfolding (and crash against side of house)

   Phone dial tone

   Phone button press

   Voice saying “911.. What’s your emergency?”

   Water glass klink

   Water splash

   Fire explosion http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhM8_wqd9CE (water poured on fire)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0RgdYkc_Po 2:00
   Baking soda box shaking

   Turning knob on stove to off

   Fire truck engine (idling, constant driving, accelerating)

   Fire truck braking

   Squealing tires

   All 3 fire truck horns http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiK0M2dOSp0

   Fire truck sirens

   Radio noise, background muffled people speaking

   Button clicks for menu (approximately 1 – 3 different noises

Answer (score 1):

Price it per sound effect (individual variations are also individual sound effects), multiply by the amount of sound effects to get the sum.

Couple of grand is not an easy price for only those sound effects that you mention, unless the game is publishable and the developers have an idea of how much revenue it may generate. It may be too large price for the audio, compared to what other costs they may have (software, art). Depends entirely on how considerable title or developer is in question.

E.g. if it's a mobile game that costs $0.99, then they'd need 1000-2000 downloads to break even just the cost of audio.

Answer (score 0):

What human said is probably a better idea for this size project. Set an amount that you want to make "per sound". Some things may take you longer than others, but it will wash with the handful of fx that you just have to record and put fades on.

Don't forget that if you're purchasing fx or props to break for foley that they are all things that are billable. Keep an itemized list when you invoice.Peace.